# Nominatim Geocoding in Python Fails With SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, dataframe, geocoding, nominatim

*Problem is encountered on Google Colab.*

I have a column 'LOCATION' in a dataframe df1:

```
df1.LOCATION
0    Cresent Lake Rd,Acworth,NH
1    Old Charlestown Tpk,Acworth,NH
2    Grout Hill Rd,Acworth,NH
3    Cold Pond Rd,Acworth,NH
4    Acworth Rd,Acworth,NH
Name: LOCATION, dtype: object
```

I then attempt to geocode the above column using Nominatim as follows:

```
Locator=Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder')
geocode=RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=5)
try:
    df1['GPS_LOC'].location=df1['LOCATION'].apply(geocode)
except:
    df1['GPS_LOC']='xxx,xxx,xxx'
```

which gives me the following message:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>   See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>     # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.

And when I look at **df1.GPS_LOC**, I can see that the exception handler is being invoked:

```
0    xxx,xxx,xxx
1    xxx,xxx,xxx
2    xxx,xxx,xxx
3    xxx,xxx,xxx
4    xxx,xxx,xxx
Name: GPS_LOC, dtype: object
```

Could someone please show me how https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy would help me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a silly mistake by me

> ```py
> df1['GPS_LOC'].location=df1['LOCATION'].apply(geocode)`
> ```

was corrected to

```py
df1['GPS_LOC']=df1['LOCATION'].apply(geocode)
```